# Uncaught Error: Object [object Object] has no method 'dispatchEvent'

Tags: javascript, lightbox

I keep getting the Uncaught Error above.. I have a basic lightbox gallery website.. It works just fine on my mac but when i upload to the server i get this error and the light box effect breaks and the pictures open in their own link.. heres my code...

```
   },

    fire: function(element, eventName, memo) {
      element = $(element);
      if (element == document && document.createEvent && !element.dispatchEvent)
        element = document.documentElement;

      var event;
      if (document.createEvent) {
        event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
        event.initEvent("dataavailable", true, true);
      } else {
        event = document.createEventObject();
        event.eventType = "ondataavailable";
      }

      event.eventName = eventName;
      event.memo = memo || { };

      if (document.createEvent) {
        element.dispatchEvent(event);
      } else {
        element.fireEvent(event.eventType, event);
      }

      return Event.extend(event);
    }
  };
})());

Object.extend(Event, Event.Methods);

Element.addMethods({
  fire:          Event.fire,
  observe:       Event.observe,
  stopObserving: Event.stopObserving
});

Object.extend(document, {
  fire:          Element.Methods.fire.methodize(),
  observe:       Element.Methods.observe.methodize(),
  stopObserving: Element.Methods.stopObserving.methodize(),
  loaded:        false
});

(function() {
  /* Support for the DOMContentLoaded event is based on work by Dan Webb,
     Matthias Miller, Dean Edwards and John Resig. */

  var timer;

  function fireContentLoadedEvent() {
    if (document.loaded) return;
    if (timer) window.clearInterval(timer);
    document.fire("dom:loaded");
    document.loaded = true;
  }
```

Comment: Maybe test for `document.dispatchEvent` instead of `document.createEvent` before trying to invoke the `dispatchEvent` method?

Comment: how do i test for that??

Comment: Did you write the code yourself? Then you should know how to test for a method.

Comment: I wrote the HTML and CSS.. i had help with the JS.. which is why I dont know quite what to write.